# How to group element by name in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm using mongoose and mongo for a new project. I'm looking to return json grouped in different categories. I'm not familiar with aggregate and I'm not sure if it's the right thing to use.

```
houseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: Number,
    name: String,
    category: String,
    });

House.aggregate(
        [
            {
                $group: {
                    "_id": {
                        "category": "$category",
                        "name": "$name"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]);
//results
[ { _id: { category: 'a', name: 'name1' } },
  { _id: { category: 'a', name: 'name2' } },
  { _id: { category: 'a', name: 'name3' } },
  { _id: { category: 'b', name: 'name4' } },
  { _id: { category: 'b', name: 'name5' } },
  { _id: { category: 'b', name: 'name6' } },
  { _id: { category: 'b', name: 'name7' } },
  { _id: { category: 'c', name: 'name8' } },
  { _id: { category: 'c', name: 'name9' } } ]
```

I would like to have something like this

```
[ { _id: { category: 'a', name: ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'] } },
  { _id: { category: 'b', name: ['name4', 'name5', 'name6', 'name7'] } },
  { _id: { category: 'c', name: ['name8', 'name9' } } ]
```

Comment: use `"name": {$addToSet: "$name"}`

Comment: exception: invalid operator \'$addToSet\'

I will look at this!

Answer (score 1):

thx @user3100115

```
House.aggregate(
        [
            {
                $group: {
                    "_id": {
                          "category": "$category",
                    },
                    "names": {
                          "$addToSet": "$name"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]);
```